# load eclipse shortcuts to jdeveloper 10.1.3.5

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 10.1.3.5.
I am trying to use Eclipse shortcuts. I opened Tools -> Preferences -> Accelerators. But there is no option like Eclipse shortcuts. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is there in newer versions of JDeveloper (11,12) - you have an import button to do that.